# Inserción duplicada en tabla HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buenas devs ayuda por favor a continuación tengo un input y junto a el un botón para agregar, dicho botón al dar click en agregar crea una mini tabla con el valor del input y junto a ese input creado en la tabla hace un cálculo que se imprime en un input readonly, pero cuando creo un valor en el input que esta junto al botón de agregar los todos los calculos en el readonly se duplican ayuda por favor. Ajunto mi código y una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi javascript para dibujar la tabla y los cálculos**

```
$('#agregarPloteo').on('click', function () {
    
    let datos = $('#metrosPloteo').val()
    if (datos != '') {
        
        html = `<tr>`;
        html += `<td><input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${datos}"></td>`
        html += `<td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetros" readonly></td>`
        html += `<td><a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>`
        html += `</tr>`
        
    }
    $('.tablaAgregarPloteo').append(html)
    
    /* AQUI PRESENTO EL PROBLEMA QUE CUANDO GUARDO SE CREA UNA DUPLICIDAD */
    /* LO QUE QUIERO ES QUE CUANDO GUARDO SE HAGA EL CALCULO AUTOMATICO Y ASI SUCESIVAMENTE UNO POR UNO 
    * PERO CUANDO GUARDO UNO SE INSERTA CORRECTAMENTE PERO CUANDO GUARDO OTRO TODOS LOS INPUTS SE ACTUALIZAN 
    * POR EL GUARDADO MAS RECIENTE */
    let metros = $('#metrosPloteo').val()
    let resultado = metros * 1.25
    $('.tablaAgregarPloteo input.metrosTotalPloteo').closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').children('input').val(resultado)
    
    /* CALCULO INDIVIDUAL EN LOS INPUTS YA CREADOS EN LA TABLA, ESTOS CALCULOS SI FUNCIONAN INDIVIDUALMENTE */
    $(document).on('keyup', '.tablaAgregarPloteo input.metrosTotalPloteo', function () {
        
        let metros = $(this).val();
        // alert(metros)
        let importe = metros * 1.25
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').children('input').val(importe)
    })
});
```

**Esta es mi vista en el html**

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <label for="metrosPloteo">Metros de Ploteo</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                       name="metrosPloteo"
                                       id="metrosPloteo"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       placeholder="1.75">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-7 align-self-end text-right">
                                <button href="#"
                                        id="agregarPloteo"
                                        class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-icon"
                                        type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Agregar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered tablaAgregarPloteo">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Metros</th>
                                            <th>Importe</th>
                                            <th>Acción</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Tu planteamiento es confuso. ¿El problema cuál es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo haciendo el cálculo dentro del input que se duplicaba

```
        html = `<tr>`;
        html += `<td><input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${datos}"></td>`;
        html += `<td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetrosPloteo" name="importeMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(datos * 1.25).toFixed(2)}" readonly></td>`;
        html += `<td><a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>`;
        html += `</tr>`;
```